# Anchor tag for downloading pdf from server working but when i download from mobile it showing me error enable plugin supports this MIME type

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

i am using anchor tag to download pdf file it works on desktop but when i use that link on mobile it gives me error "enable plugin supports this MIME type"

```
<div>
  <a href="https://360clients.in/psnewsportal/careers/India%202050%20hindi%20chrome.pdf" download>
    Download
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your PHP and your  `<form>` tag  please ?

Comment: i am not having any form tag i am having a link only that store in database mysql i am only fetching that link

Comment: I see better the use case my bad !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download: _"How browsers treat downloads varies by browser, user settings, and other factors. The user may be prompted before a download starts, or the file may be saved automatically, or it may open automatically, either in an external application or in the browser itself."_ - so there is no _guarantee_ this will work as you want it to, to begin with. If you want something that works more reliably across the board - then use a solution that forces the download by sending appropriate response headers.